# Can I use the same SSL cert on two separate networks?

Tags: https, web-hosting, apache2

We offer an application over HTTPS which is going to be moved, from our external DMZ (https://app.mycorp.com), onto our LAN (internal DNS also answers for app.mycorp.com). The application will need to be accessed now over VPN.

The developer wishes to leave the external view DNS A/PTR records in place to allow for an "info" page (404 page) which would remind people to connect to the service over VPN if they inadvertently attempt to load the site from a bookmark (while at a coffee shop for instance). Since the site is primarily wrapped with HTTPS, people likely have the HTTPS URL bookmarked.

The only way I can think of to make SSL work for both the internal app, and external 404 page, is to use the same SSL cert in both places. Will there be a conflict on the user's browser since they've connected to two different sites which offer the same cert?  I think HTTPS only cares about DNS returning the correct hostname from the CN in the cert, correct?

Is another way to do this? I don't think we can redirect (via Nginx) an HTTPS bookmark to HTTP without the browser (understandably) taking an issue with it so I think that solution is out.

Comment: Yes, this works.

Comment: I don't see any reason you need to use the same cert, although you can as long as it has the name(s?) used for both servers. HTTPS requires that the SubjectAltName _extension_ (aka SAN aka UCC aka multidomain) in the cert if present (and it is present for nearly all public-CA certs since Obama's first term) and otherwise CN (rarely) _match_ (which can include wildcards) the hostname reuqested. ...

Comment: ... OTOH redirecting HTTPS to HTTP on a different DNS name is fine, and even on the same name it's fine _unless_ your server has been issuing HSTS to the browsers (and your HSTS time hasn't expired). But if someone is accessing the external server not through VPN then a redirect won't go through VPN either and won't reach the internal server.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 As far as I understood, they don't want to redirect people accessing the site without VPN, but serve them a note that they should use the VPN.

Comment: @gf_ Yes - this is correct. We only want to display an "info page" that says "hey, use the VPN for this resource. It's not available from the internet". I can accomplish this with a virtual site hosting the SSL certs and a CNAME in DNS all pointing to one of our existing external  servers.  The server available over VPN would  be the actual application server and no redirection.  PS If you want to submit your response I can select it as answered

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the tip about HSTS - it's things like these that often get overlooked and found out later

Comment: If you're using HTTPS for both sites, which is your plan as far as I understood, you're fine, as I wrote in the beginning, even if you're sending HSTS headers. You're using the same cert with the same hostname, so you're good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using HTTPS for both sites, which is your plan as far as I understood, you're fine, as I wrote in the beginning, even if you're sending HSTS headers. You're using the same cert with the same hostname, so you're good to go.